# Why does Process.fork make stuff slower in Ruby on OS X?

Tags: ruby, macos, performance, unix, fork

Can someone explain to me why `Process.fork` makes stuff so much slower in Ruby? I'm using Ruby 2.3.1 on OS X El Capitan.

```
require 'time'
require 'benchmark'

def do_stuff
  50000.times { Time.parse(Time.utc(2016).iso8601) }
end

puts Benchmark.measure { do_stuff } # => 1.660000   0.010000   1.670000 (  1.675466)

Process.fork do
  puts Benchmark.measure { do_stuff } # => 3.170000   6.250000   9.420000 (  9.508235)
end
```

EDIT: Just noticed that running that code on Linux (tested Debian or Ubuntu) does not result in a negative performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

**"Why does Process.fork make stuff slower in Ruby on OS X?"**

Step one in getting to the bottom of this is to reduce the number of variables.

Your example of running `Time.parse(Time.utc(2016).iso8601)` fifty thousand times seems oddly specific. I reformulated the benchmark test using a different "slow" Ruby task:

```
require 'benchmark'

def do_stuff
  a = [nil] * 200

  10.times do
    a.each {|x| a.each {|y| a.each {|z| ; }}}; ()
  end
end

puts "main: #{Benchmark.measure { do_stuff }}"

Process.fork do
  puts "fork: #{Benchmark.measure { do_stuff }}"
end
```

Here I've replaced your `Time` commands with a no-op nested loop over a large array.

The results:

```
main:   4.020000   0.010000   4.030000 (  4.050664)
fork:   3.940000   0.000000   3.940000 (  3.962207)

main:   3.840000   0.010000   3.850000 (  3.856188)
fork:   3.850000   0.000000   3.850000 (  3.865250)

main:   3.930000   0.000000   3.930000 (  3.937741)
fork:   3.970000   0.000000   3.970000 (  3.986397)

main:   4.340000   0.010000   4.350000 (  4.370009)
fork:   4.300000   0.000000   4.300000 (  4.308156)
```

No noticeable pattern of the forked process being slower or faster. I've tested in Ruby 1.9, 2.0, and 2.3 on both OS X and Ubuntu, and it remains the same.

The answer to your question is:

**`Process.fork` does not, in general, make stuff slower in Ruby on OS X.**

However, there is a different interesting question here, which is [Why is `Time.utc` slower in a forked process in Ruby on OS X (and not in Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353532/why-is-time-utc-slower-in-a-forked-process-in-ruby-on-os-x)