# Why is Time.utc slower in a forked process in Ruby on OS X (and not in Python)?

Tags: python, ruby, performance, fork

I saw the question [Why does Process.fork make stuff slower in Ruby on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38844392/why-does-process-fork-make-stuff-slower-in-ruby-on-os-x) and was able to determine that `Process.fork` does *not* actually make tasks, in general, slower.

However, it does seem to make `Time.utc`, in particular, much slower.

```
require 'benchmark'

def do_stuff
  50000.times { Time.utc(2016) }
end

puts "main: #{Benchmark.measure { do_stuff }}"

Process.fork do
  puts "fork: #{Benchmark.measure { do_stuff }}"
end
```

Here are some results:

```
main:   0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.103762)
fork:   0.530000   3.210000   3.740000 (  3.765203)

main:   0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.104218)
fork:   0.540000   3.280000   3.820000 (  3.858817)

main:   0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.102956)
fork:   0.520000   3.280000   3.800000 (  3.831084)
```

One clue might be that the above takes place on OS X, whereas on Ubuntu, there doesn't seem to be a difference:

```
main:   0.100000   0.070000   0.170000 (  0.166505)
fork:   0.090000   0.070000   0.160000 (  0.169578)

main:   0.090000   0.080000   0.170000 (  0.167889)
fork:   0.100000   0.060000   0.160000 (  0.169160)

main:   0.100000   0.070000   0.170000 (  0.170839)
fork:   0.100000   0.070000   0.170000 (  0.176146)
```

Can anyone explain this oddity?

**Further investigation:**

[@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) suggested that it might be a bug in the macOS / OS X time code, so I wrote a similar test in Python:

```
from timeit import timeit
from os import fork

print timeit("datetime.datetime.utcnow()", setup="import datetime")

if fork() == 0:
  print timeit("datetime.datetime.utcnow()", setup="import datetime")
else:
  pass
```

Again, on Ubuntu, the benchmarks are the same for the forked/main processes. On OS X, however, the forked process is now slightly *faster* than the main process, which is the *opposite* of the behavior in Ruby.

This leads me to believe that the source of the "fork penalty" is in the Ruby implementation and not in the OS X time implementation.

Comment: Is it a penalty per fork layer, like would it be double if in another sub-fork? Does that penalty go away if the parent process exits? Does this apply inside of threads?

Comment: @tadman Cool questions. It is not a penalty per fork layer; the next-level fork has the exact same execution time as the first fork. I'll check the rest of the scenarios if I can.

Comment: I'm observing the same behaviour as you with Ruby 2.3.3 on macOS 10.12, but can't reproduce it on Fedora. This is likely an issue with the time code on macOS, so it might be worth filing a bug report. I believe this is isolated to time-related functions for some reason.

Comment: @tadman Subsequent deeper layers of forking all experience the exact same penalty, and the penalty does not change depending on whether the parent process exits or not. Regarding Fedora: that matches the Ubuntu behavior I mentioned, so I would expect all Linux distros to avoid the penalty encountered on macOS / OS X.

Comment: @tadman I updated with a test script in Python that (I believe) shows the "fork penalty" is exclusive to Ruby. My Python is only so-so, and so I may have drawn a bad conclusion; I added the python tag to the question to see if any Python experts object to my test.

Comment: Can you find any other functions other than time-related which exhibit this behaviour? It's probably a simple thing in the Ruby C code, but a very quirky one.

Comment: I can also reproduce this behavior on Ruby 2.0.0p648 on OSX 10.12.1 compared to Ruby 2.0.0p598 on CentOS 7.2.1511. What's more, it consistently differs by year in `Time.utc`. 1972-2017: slow (5s). 1970-1971: medium (2.5s). 1950-1969, 2018-2040: fast (0.1s, no difference). No difference in other code like `File.exists?` (syscalls) or large string concat (heavy allocations). I have no idea what to make of this.

Comment: @thatotherguy I get similar results with Ruby 2.4. The dates are interesting though: 1970 is the UNIX epoch, 1972 is ([according to the Ruby source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0/time.c#L1140-L1141)) when the first leap-second occurred, and leap-seconds (again [according to the Ruby source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0/time.c#L1094-L1096)) are known 6 months in advance, so that would be into 2017 but not 2018. I still can’t see how this would differ between the parent process and a forked child though.

Comment: @matt I'm with you – I saw that the dates are related to leap seconds, but I'm still confused as to why the main/fork processes would differ. I experimented with IO pipes but couldn't find a relationship.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out, the slowdown is due in approximately equal measure to two function calls in `time.c`, in the function `gmtime_with_leapsecond`. The two functions are `tzset` and `localtime_r`.

That discovery led me to the question [Why is tzset() a lot slower after forking on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932330/why-is-tzset-a-lot-slower-after-forking-on-mac-os-x), of which the current question might reasonably be said to be a duplicate.

There are two answers there, neither accepted, which point to root causes involving either

- the "async-signal-safe"-ness of `tzset` and `localtime`/`localtime_r`, or
- Apple's use of a passive notification registry that invalidates when `fork`'d.

The fact that the slowdown only occurs in years with no known leap seconds (as discovered by user [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy)) is obviously due to the fact that Ruby doesn't call `gmtime_with_leapsecond` when it knows that the year has no leap seconds.

I'm not sure why there is no such slowdown in Python. One possible explanation is that my test script using `fork` and `utcnow` may not be creating a child process that calls `tzset` or `localtime`/`localtime_r`.